# How to run PHP using Python?

Tags: python, php, programming

I'm looking for PHP interpreter for my Python app.

Basically I'd like to invoke PHP code within Python codebase. Are there any libraries or language interpreters which makes it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found so far these PHP interpreters for Python:

- [iksteen/pyhp at GitHub](https://github.com/iksteen/pyhp) (MIT)

  Example:

  ```
  >>> import pyhp
  >>> pyhp.evaluate('echo $foo;', {'foo': 'bar'})
  'bar'
  >>> pyhp.execute('foo.php', {'foo': 'bar'})
  ```
- [php-in-python](https://bitbucket.org/moriyoshi/php-in-python) ([pypi package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/php-in-python/0.1))

  > Running PHP interpreter within Python.